# RegisterStartUpScript - clear code when postback occurs

Tags: c#, javascript, updatepanel

I am using a stringbuilder object to concatenate some javascript together and then register it.  My question is, is there a way using client side Javascript to clear that javascript when a postback occurs.  I have found out that when registering arrays using the scriptmanager you have to empty down any dynamic arrays and basically I want to do the same thing with the javascript code that I am dynamically adding to the page?  The javascript has a key ("randomlists") so we must be able to reference it!

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel_MyPublications, typeof(UpdatePanel), "randomlists", sb_javascript.ToString(), true);
```

Let me explain a little more.  The javascript that I am registering contains some variables, in this case some other arrays which are dynamically populated.  Currently the error is that these arrays are appended to rather than reinstantiated and re-populated (lots of 're' going on) and if I could simply clear and re-register the code all the problems would magically stop...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On post back re-registering the script using the same name, but different content (ie. different string builder) *should* work.

On the aspx page, add a button called "Button1", and use the following aspx.cs as a proof of concept. Clicking the button after page load alerts "1", and then posts back.  Click the button again and you'll get an alert "2", showing that on post back, I was able to redefine the variable.

aspx.cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(test);");
        var sb_javascript = new StringBuilder();
        var sb_javascriptPostback = new StringBuilder();
        sb_javascript.Append("var test='1';");
        sb_javascriptPostback.Append("var test='2';");
        if ((Page.IsPostBack))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel_MyPublications, typeof(UpdatePanel), "randomlists", sb_javascriptPostback.ToString(),
                                                true);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel_MyPublications, typeof (UpdatePanel), "randomlists",
                                                sb_javascript.ToString(),
                                                true);
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("PostBack");
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, please post your code so we can take a look at your specific scenario.